# How to pass member from a list as string to another function?

Tags: elisp

This is my first ever elisp program. I'm trying to make a dashboard of sorts to display when Emacs starts up.  I'm following code from the elisp startup page [startup.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/startup.el):

```
(defun dashboard ()
  "Display a custom dashboard on startup"
  (let ((dash-buffer (get-buffer-create "*dashboard*")))
    (with-current-buffer dash-buffer
      (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
        (erase-buffer)

        (fancy-splash-insert
         :face 'variable-pitch "Recent Files:"
         :face 'variable-pitch "\n")

        (dolist (recent recentf-list)
          (defconst file-text
            `((:link ((with-output-to-string (princ recent)),
                      (lambda (_button) (browse-url "https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/"))
                      ))))

          (apply #'fancy-splash-insert (car file-text))
          (insert "\n")))

      (display-buffer dash-buffer))))
```

I want to ultimately display the recently used files, so I walk over the list with `(dolist (recent recentf-list)`, so `recent` in theory holds a recently used file.  I would like to then make a link out of the variable `recent`.  Yes I realize that a link to gnu.org is not exactly what I want, but I have not made it to the link part yet.  I think something with find-file is what I want there, but I'll get to that later.  At any rate, try as I might, the only thing I can make work is a hard coded string:

--works

```
`((:link ("foo",
```

--does not work

```
`((:link (recent,

`((:link ((format "%s" recent),

`((:link ((with-output-to-string (princ recent)),
```

I've tried everything I can think of to get this thing to take a variable and it is defeating me...any ideas?

I'm getting errors similar to the following:

```
fancy-splash-insert: Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p, (with-output-to-string (princ recent))
```

Comment: You need to use the special marker `,` to tell the backquote that recent is not a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the special marker `,` to tell the backquote that `recent` is not a constant. You also don't need `princ` nor `with output to string`. This should work:

```
(defun dashboard ()
  "Display a custom dashboard on startup"
  (let ((dash-buffer (get-buffer-create "*dashboard*")))
    (with-current-buffer dash-buffer
      (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
        (erase-buffer)

        (fancy-splash-insert
         :face 'variable-pitch "Recent Files:"
         :face 'variable-pitch "\n")

        (dolist (recent recentf-list)
          (defconst file-text
            `((:link (,recent
                      (lambda (_button) (browse-url "https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/"))
                      ))))

          (apply #'fancy-splash-insert (car file-text))
          (insert "\n")))

      (display-buffer dash-buffer))))
```

See more info about the backquote in [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, that does work indeed.  I must say that is some odd syntax though, and thank you for pointing me to the backquote documentation. It seems I need to learn more about that.